# How to show all tagged commits not reachable by a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

In my local repo, sometimes there are tags tagging a commit with no children and no branch name.

I originally created these by branching off my main development line normally, setting a tag, and then deleting the branch.  They don't get garbage-collected because the tag holds the line open.

Is there a command that will identify all such commits?   It doesn't matter whether or not this command also finds the branch heads as I can identify them easily enough with `git show-ref --heads`.

I'd like to clean them up (either remove the tags and GC the line I don't need any more; or set a branch there which I believe is better practice).

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're looking for. `git tag` will list all your tags, and `git for-each-ref` lets you write scripts that look at *all* references (branches, tags, notes, `refs/stash`, whatever). You might then write code / a script that finds commits located by some reference that's not a branch, that's not reachable from any reference that *is* a branch, if that's what your goal is.

Answer (score 3):

Use `git tag` to list all the tags. Test if they are reachable from one or more branches.

Something like:

```
git tag | while read tag
do
    echo Tag is $tag
    git branch -a --contains $tag
    echo ""
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL, DR**

On `bash` or similar

```
$ git tag $(git branch --all --list --format="--no-merged %(refname:short) ")
```

**Explanation**

The `--no-merged [<commit>]` option to `git tag` shows all tags not reachable from the given commit (defaulting to head). The neat thing is that one can use `--no-merged` multiple times.

Suppose you have this situation:

```
$ git log --oneline --all --graph
* 075bf49 (tag: TagNotOnAnyBranch) some commit
* 08f76af (tag: ValidTag, main) Second commit on main
| * 11d1be8 (HEAD -> feature) Commit on feature
|/
* 94f12ca First commit on main
```

If you could run

```
$ git tag --no-merged main --no-merged feature
TagNotOnAnyBranch
```

you get the correct result. But this is tiring if there are many branches. You can use the branch command to create all the `--no-merged` parameters for you:

```
$ git branch --all --list --format="--no-merged %(refname:short) "
--no-merged feature
--no-merged main
```

If you are using `bash` or similar, and putting it all together:

```
$ git tag $(git branch --all --list --format="--no-merged %(refname:short) ")
TagNotOnAnyBranch
```

**Caveat**: If you have many branches, you may run into the maximum length of a command in terms of characters.